# setInterval() not stopping on time, "jumping" between intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a web app to help with a restaurant, and my client was very clear on that he wanted the app to be asynchronous.

During localhost development I used setInterval to update the page periodicaly using variations of this code for each button:

```
$('#showWaitlist').click(function(){
    showWaitlist();
    stopUpdate(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() { showWaitlist();}, intervalTime); 
});

function stopUpdate(){  
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

So that every time I click a button it stops the past interval and starts it's own.
It worked fine, however, when I moved the app to the server the intevals would sometimes overlap each other, specially when the server was on heavier-than-avarage load or when I used a phone to access the site.

If setInterval and stopUpdate are js shouldn't they work on clientside and be practically instant? What could cause this "jumping" between intervals?
This is a link to the website: http://www.emc2.mx/Pruebas/unicenta/PostodoroApp/

Please note that the problem not always happens, but you can probably replicate it if you opne it on your phone.

I'll add showWaitlist here, but I doubt there's something wrong with it.

```
function showWaitlist(){
    $.ajax({                
        type:'GET',
        url: 'waitlist.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#result_table').html(result);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call 
}
```

Comment: what is the code for stopUpdate()?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I forgot it was not vanilla js. I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You will need to clear the interval in 
the success of the ajax call on your code by adding the following line

```
clearInterval(interval); // stop the timer once the time finishes.
```

after the following line

```
$('#result_table').html(result);
```

You need to have access of the interval variable in the success method callback

Comment: Won't that prevent it from updating? I only want to stop the updating if I click a diferent button. If I clear on ajax success it will cause to only update once won't it?

Comment: so you have to capture the body click event and 
$('body').click(function(evt){    
       if(evt.target.id !== "showWaitlist") {
             // call clearInterval
       }
}